# non attached Image.onload garbage collection

Tags: javascript, event-handling, garbage-collection

If an image is created via `var img=new Image()`, an `onload` handler is added and `img.src` is set, the image data will be requested, and `onload` called despite the image is not attached to the DOM tree. Eg.

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    alert('Loaded!');
}
img.src='test.png';
```

When and how this image is garbage collected? Is JavaScript capable of knowing that the `onload`handler will be called, and called only once, to free the image afterwards? Will JavaScript notice if `img.src` is not set and thus `onload` will never be called and `img`can be freed immediately?

Answer (score 6):

I've done some investigation using a [test page](http://pastebin.com/YZkGYmBC) to find the answer to the question - when image objects with event handlers, created in JS and not attached to DOM tree, are garbage collected.

The JS code in the page creates 1000 images via `document.createElement("img")` (`new Image()` works the same way), attaches 2 events handlers (load and error) and sets `src` property.
When all images are loaded, JS tries to free up the memory explicitly calling `gc()` in the last load event (=synchronously) and immediately sets the `src` of this image to another URL. Also, timer is set to make the second attempt to free up the memory, so it's done in async fashion later.

Memory Timeline in Chrome Developer Tools shows that the first GC collects all images except the last. I interpret this as the last image could not be GC'ed, because it is loading new picture.
When the 2nd GC occurs, the last image is already loaded and it is removed from the memory too.

[image: Memory Timeline]

My conclusions from this experiment:

- load/error event handlers are invoked, event if no links to an image
  objects exist in JS,
- image objects can be garbage collected when the process of image loading has finished (succeeded or failed).

Tested in Chrome Canary 33.0.1733.2 with `--js-flags="--expose-gc"`

Source code http://pastebin.com/YZkGYmBC

Comment: This seems like a quite reasonable behaviour. Hope other browsers will handle this equally well.